# Error NaN: undefined Reason: undefined: Getting error after 1 minute

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

I have developed a Spring boot application, with React as Frontend. I'm Steaming a PDF back to the browser. However, when a Request goes to the Controller, and when the processing takes longer than 1 minute, I get an error on the Screen **Error NaN: undefined Reason: undefined**

I have tried increasing the timeout in both front as well as backend, but no luck. I'm not sure if this is related to timeout or not. Can someone please help. Below is the stack trace.

```
2023-03-06 12:22:33.678 DEBUG 13380 --- [-nio-443-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/print/error?error=undefined&message=undefined&reason=undefined", parameters={masked}
2023-03-06 12:22:33.680 DEBUG 13380 --- [-nio-443-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.jcrew.labelprintbackend.controllers.FrontendController#print()
2023-03-06 12:22:33.682 DEBUG 13380 --- [-nio-443-exec-2] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7, */*;q=0.8]
2023-03-06 12:22:33.682 DEBUG 13380 --- [-nio-443-exec-2] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : View name 'forward:', model {}
2023-03-06 12:22:33.682 DEBUG 13380 --- [-nio-443-exec-2] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : Forwarding to [/index.html]
2023-03-06 12:22:33.682 DEBUG 13380 --- [-nio-443-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "FORWARD" dispatch for GET "/index.html?error=undefined&message=undefined&reason=undefined", parameters={masked}
2023-03-06 12:22:33.684 DEBUG 13380 --- [-nio-443-exec-2] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [Classpath [META-INF/resources/], Classpath [resources/], Classpath [static/], Classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
2023-03-06 12:22:33.687 DEBUG 13380 --- [-nio-443-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "FORWARD" dispatch, status 200
2023-03-06 12:22:33.687 DEBUG 13380 --- [-nio-443-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2023-03-06 12:22:33.723 DEBUG 13380 --- [-nio-443-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/static/css/2.eefd091c.chunk.css", parameters={}
2023-03-06 12:22:33.726 DEBUG 13380 --- [-nio-443-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [Classpath [META-INF/resources/], Classpath [resources/], Classpath [static/], Classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
2023-03-06 12:22:33.766 DEBUG 13380 --- [-nio-443-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/static/js/2.7df57dd0.chunk.js", parameters={}
2023-03-06 12:22:33.767 DEBUG 13380 --- [-nio-443-exec-4] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [Classpath [META-INF/resources/], Classpath [resources/], Classpath [static/], Classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
2023-03-06 12:22:33.768 DEBUG 13380 --- [-nio-443-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2023-03-06 12:22:33.774 DEBUG 13380 --- [nio-443-exec-10] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/static/js/main.2f79f0d9.chunk.js", parameters={}
2023-03-06 12:22:33.776 DEBUG 13380 --- [nio-443-exec-10] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [Classpath [META-INF/resources/], Classpath [resources/], Classpath [static/], Classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
2023-03-06 12:22:33.777 DEBUG 13380 --- [-nio-443-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/static/css/main.bc6778fd.chunk.css", parameters={}
2023-03-06 12:22:33.778 DEBUG 13380 --- [-nio-443-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [Classpath [META-INF/resources/], Classpath [resources/], Classpath [static/], Classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
2023-03-06 12:22:33.805 DEBUG 13380 --- [nio-443-exec-10] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2023-03-06 12:22:33.832 DEBUG 13380 --- [-nio-443-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2023-03-06 12:22:33.859 DEBUG 13380 --- [-nio-443-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2023-03-06 12:22:33.927 DEBUG 13380 --- [-nio-443-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/favicon.ico", parameters={}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED : The problem was with the Load Balancer's time out value. It was set to 1 minute. Once this value was increased, the timeout problem got solved.